# How does \pgfkeysvalueof work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

With this minimal example

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
line width  = 5cm,
CC/.initial = 7cm
}
It doesn't works :\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/line width}

It works : \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/CC}
\end{document}
```

I can't get the value of line width, on the contrary of CC. Why? Is it because CC is stored like plain text and line width is not? How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The shown difference has nothing to do with how `\pgfkeysvalueof` works. This macro simply expands to the given key, i.e. it is defined as `\csname pgfk@#1\endcsname`, so you get `\pgfk@/tikz/CC` and `\pgfk@/tikz/line width` (using `\csname` you can have spaces and other non-letters in the macro name).

The difference is in the way these keys were defined. The `/tikz/line width` got defined as `.code={\tikz@semiaddlinewidth {#1}}`. This defines a macro called `\pgfk@/tikz/line width/.@cmd` which holds that code and stores the values somewhere else. If you use the key PGF/TikZ (i.e., `pgfkeys`) checks if a `.@cmd` is defined and executes that code.

Now, `/tikz/CC` is defined using `.initial` which stores the `7cm` value directly in in the key, i.e., in the macro `\pgfk@/tikz/CC`. You then can get the value again using `\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/CC}` which expands to this macro.

So, you can't just use `\pgfkeysvalueof` on arbitrary keys you  didn't define yourself and hope they work. The internal implementation can be more complicated than a simple assignment. In the case of the line width I can help you. The final line width is stored in `\pgflinewidth` which is a dimension register, i.e., you can use it using a factor like `0.5\pgflinewidth`.

Comment: Additionally, is there any way to get the line width of specific style, e.g. `/tikz/very thin` (although manual specifies it is `0.2pt` in this case)?